# unmarshalling empty element with a single attribute

Tags: java, jaxb

```
<animals>
    <dog name="Pluto"></dog>
</animals>
```

If a would like to unmarshall such xml, I need to create classes Animals and Dog.
Is the possibility to create only one class?

```
public class Animals{
    private String dog; // value of this field should be "Pluto"
    private void setDog(String dog);
    private String getDog();
}
```

How should I annotate methods in Animals?

Answer (score 1):

No, you will still need 2 classes, but you can hide the Dog class, and expose the same methods on your outer class:

```
public class Animals{
    private @XmlElement Dog dog; 

    public void setDog(String dogName) {
       dog = new Dog();
       dog.name = dogName;
    }

    public String getDog() {
       return dog.name;
    }


    public static class Dog {
       private @XmlAttribute String name;
    }
}
```

Comment: You could leverage an `XmlAdapter` to keep the Dog class out of your domain model:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6871469/unmarshalling-empty-element-with-a-single-attribute/6871995#6871995

Answer (score 1):

**Note:**  I'm the [EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) lead, and a member of the JAXB ([JSR-222](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222)) expert group.

> Is the possibility to create only one class?

Yes, this can be done in a couple of different ways:

1. Using an `XmlAdapter`
2. Using MOXy's `@XmlPath` extension

**Option 1 - XmlAdapter**

This approach is similar to what was [suggested by skaffman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6871469/unmarshalling-empty-element-with-a-single-attribute/6871782#6871782) only it keeps the logic out of your domain model:

```
package forum6871469;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter;

public class DogAdapter extends XmlAdapter<DogAdapter.Dog, String> {

    @Override
    public Dog marshal(String name) throws Exception {
        Dog dog = new Dog();
        dog.name = name;
        return dog;
    }

    @Override
    public String unmarshal(Dog dog) throws Exception {
        return dog.name;
    }

    public static class Dog {

        @XmlAttribute
        public String name;
    }

}
```

The `XmlAdapter` is referenced using the `@XmlJavaTypeAdaper` annotation:

```
package forum6871469;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlJavaTypeAdapter;

@XmlRootElement
public class Animals{
    private String dog; // value of this field should be "Pluto"

    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(DogAdapter.class)
    public String getDog() {
       return dog;
    }

    public void setDog(String dogName) {
       dog = dogName;
    }

}
```

***For More Information***

- http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/07/xmladapter-jaxbs-secret-weapon.html

**Option 2 - MOXy's @XmlPath Extension**

You can use the `@XmlPath` extension in MOXy to map this use case:

```
package forum6871469;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.annotations.XmlPath;

@XmlRootElement
public class Animals{
    private String dog; // value of this field should be "Pluto"

    @XmlPath("dog/@name")
    public String getDog() {
       return dog;
    }

    public void setDog(String dogName) {
       dog = dogName;
    }

}
```

***For More Information***

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/07/xpath-based-mapping.html
- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/09/xpath-based-mapping-geocode-example.html
- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/03/map-to-element-based-on-attribute-value.html
- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/05/specifying-eclipselink-moxy-as-your.html